# Why does casting infinity into byte or short equal -1 in Java?

Tags: java, type-conversion, byte, short, infinity

Recently I found out that if you take a double or float and divide it by 0 that you get infinity as value. I converted infinity to every datatype (by writing `(byte)variable`, `(short)variable` etc.) and I found out that if you convert it into byte or short it gives the value -1, but if you convert it into any other datatype it gives you the max value of it back. I was wondering why that happened. Anyone got a guess?

Here is the code im using to test it.

```
double dsa = 1.00 / 0;

System.out.println("Byte");
System.out.println((byte)dsa);
System.out.println(Byte.MAX_VALUE + "\n");

System.out.println("Short");
System.out.println((short)dsa);
System.out.println(Short.MAX_VALUE + "\n");

System.out.println("Integer");
System.out.println((int)dsa);
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + "\n");

System.out.println("Long");
System.out.println((long)dsa);
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE + "\n");

System.out.println("Float");
System.out.println((float)dsa);
System.out.println(Float.MAX_VALUE + "\n");

System.out.println("Double");
System.out.println((double)dsa);
System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE + "\n");
```

And here is what the console gives me:

```
Byte
-1
127

Short
-1
32767

Integer
2147483647
2147483647

Long
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775807

Float
Infinity
3.4028235E38

Double
Infinity
1.7976931348623157E308
```

Comment: "I converted infinity" - Can we see your code?

Comment: Did you mean "casted" instead of "converted"?

Comment: I added the code to it and I might mean casted instead. sorry i dont learn about programming in english so im not sure. just look at the code.

Answer (score -1):

Because positive infinity is defined as `0x7ff0000000000000`. From `Double` class source code:

```
/**
 * A constant holding the positive infinity of type
 * {@code double}. It is equal to the value returned by
 * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff0000000000000L)}.
 */
public static final double POSITIVE_INFINITY = 1.0 / 0.0;
```

Also please note that *casting* is not *converting*.

Comment: sorry if it might sound stupid to you or something but why does 0x7ff0000000000000 give -1 in byte or short but the max value in other types?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I somehow read 0 instead of -1 :/